# Filtering of count data based on replicates and value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data.frame:

[image]

The first column contains names (of genes), column 2-4 contains counts of one condition in three replicates, and column 5-7 counts of a second condition in three replicates.
Now, I would like to filter out all genes, that

- have at least values in 2 out of 3 replicates (one value can be 0 or missing)
- have counts ≥ 3 per condition

This is my data:

```
test = read.table(text="Geneid  exp1    exp2    exp3    stat1   stat2   stat3
gene_0001   12  11  18  115 103 97
gene_0002   1   2   0   18  21  20
gene_0003   3   3   0   3   0   0
gene_0004   1   1   0   1   2   0
gene_0005   50  0   0   20  0   0
gene_0006   0   0   1   1   0   0
gene_0007   0   2   3   0   2   3", header=TRUE, row.names=1)
```

And I started doing this by creating a binary matrix, and, filters my data using `dplyr`:

```
bin_data <- test
bin_data[bin_data == 0] <- NA
idx <- is.na(bin_data)
bin_data[!idx] <- 1
bin_data[idx] <- 0

# Now, I make a second data.frame out of my columnnames, so that I have the information of condition and replicate number:
my_columns=data.frame(row.names=as.vector(colnames(test)), as.vector(colnames(test)))
colnames(my_columns) = "condition"
my_columns$label = my_columns$condition
my_columns$ID = my_columns$condition
my_columns$replicate = substr(my_columns$condition, nchar(my_columns$condition)-1+1, nchar(my_columns$condition))
my_columns$condition = substr(my_columns$condition,1,nchar(my_columns$condition)-1)
my_columns$condition = as.factor(my_columns$condition)

# Now comes the actual filtering:
keep <- bin_data %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(ID, value, -rowname) %>%
  left_join(., data.frame(my_columns), by = "ID") %>%
  group_by(rowname, condition) %>%
  summarize(miss_val = n() - sum(value)) %>%
  filter(miss_val <= 1) %>% # in two out of three replicates
  spread(condition, miss_val)
test2 <- test[keep$rowname, ]

# Now I filter my data that so that there are at least 3 counts
test2 %>%
  filter_all(., any_vars(. >= 3))
```

In the last step, however, it does not take into account the group ("condition"), because otherwise `gene_0007` is not filtered out. How do I make it account for the ≥3 PER condition?

This is my expected output:

[image]

Comment: FYI, *"first column contains names"* is great, but using `row.names=1` breaks that by converting the column of `Geneid` into `row.names`. Not the same thing.

Comment: `gene_0007` has exp of `0,2,3` and stat of `0,2,3`; both conditions have 2 or more values above 0, and the sum of each is above 3. Why is it not in your expected output?

Comment: FYI, `tidyr` has shifted from `gather`/`spread` to `pivot_*` functions; they are much more powerful and worth migrating your muscle-memory and processes.

Comment: It’s not about the sum, but each value of a replicate per condition. It gets filtered out because after filtering based on my first rule, the one of the two replIcates is less than 3. And thanks for pointing out ‘tidyr’, I’ll check it out!

Comment: Your first rule is *"have at least values in 2 out of 3"*: 0007 has 2 non-zero values, so it should be good. How am I misinterpreting that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly

### Example data

```
test = read.table(
text="Geneid exp1  exp2  exp3  stat1  stat2  stat3
gene_0001 12 11 18 115 103 97
gene_0002 1  2  0  18 21 20
gene_0003 3  3  0  3  0  0
gene_0004 1  1  0  1  2  0
gene_0005 50 0  0  20 0  0
gene_0006 0  0  1  1  0  0
gene_0007 0  2  3  0  2  3", header=TRUE)
test
```

### Code

```
test %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(
      #First condition, at least 2 exp columns > 0
      aux_condition1 = sum(c_across(cols = starts_with("exp")) > 0),
      #First condition, at least 2 stat columns > 0
      aux_condition2 = sum(c_across(cols = starts_with("stat")) > 0),
      #Second condition, at least 1 stat column > 2
      aux_condition3 = sum(c_across(cols = starts_with("stat")) > 2),
      #Second condition, at least 1 exp column > 2
      aux_condition4 = sum(c_across(cols = starts_with("exp")) > 2)
      ) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   filter(
      aux_condition1 > 1 | aux_condition2 > 1,
      aux_condition3 > 1 | aux_condition4 > 1) %>%
   #Remove auxiliar variables
   select(-starts_with("aux_"))
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
  Geneid     exp1  exp2  exp3 stat1 stat2 stat3
  <chr>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 gene_0001    12    11    18   115   103    97
2 gene_0002     1     2     0    18    21    20
3 gene_0003     3     3     0     3     0     0
```

Comment: Rhank you, almost! The min 3 should not be summed up per group, but rather considered every cell value!

Comment: Updated @Saraha, still gene_0007 remains, I failed to see how it does not falls in the conditions

Comment: thank you, I understand your logic now! I changed `aux_condition3` to `aux_condition3 = sum(c_across(cols = starts_with("stat")) > 2)` and made also `aux_condition4 = sum(c_across(cols = starts_with("exp")) > 2)`, so that I can then filter it by `aux_condition3 > 1 | aux_condition4 > 1)`. `gene_0007` then gets removed :)

Comment: I see, updated the answer if someone else needs!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(test, -Geneid, names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)$",
             names_to = c("type", "num"), values_to = "val") %>%
  group_by(Geneid, type) %>%
  filter(sum(!is.na(val) & val > 0) >= 2, all(val[val>0] >= 3)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(Geneid, .keep_all = FALSE) %>%
  left_join(test, by = "Geneid")
# # A tibble: 3 x 7
#   Geneid     exp1  exp2  exp3 stat1 stat2 stat3
#   <chr>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 gene_0001    12    11    18   115   103    97
# 2 gene_0002     1     2     0    18    21    20
# 3 gene_0003     3     3     0     3     0     0
```

---

Data: I modified the load slightly to remove `row.names=1` so that `Geneid` is an actual column.

```r
test <- structure(list(Geneid = c("gene_0001", "gene_0002", "gene_0003", "gene_0004", "gene_0005", "gene_0006", "gene_0007"), exp1 = c(12L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 50L, 0L, 0L), exp2 = c(11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L), exp3 = c(18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L), stat1 = c(115L, 18L, 3L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 0L), stat2 = c(103L, 21L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L), stat3 = c(97L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thank you, howevery gene_0007 should be discarded because both exp2 and stat2 have a count of 2 instead of 3, although they do meet the criteria of only 1 missing value.

Comment: How is your first rule relevant? If a rule passes *"have counts ≥ 3 per condition"*, then without exception all replicates (not just *"2 out of 3"*) will have values.

Comment: Try that logic on your real data. Perhaps I'm just misunderstand your rules.